# Showing $D(f) \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}D(f_{n})$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

I feel like I have written an "overkill" argument for this problem, but I wanted to be thorough.

> Let $(X,d)$ and  $(Y,\rho)$ be metric spaces, and let $f, f_{n} :X \to Y$ with $f_{n} ⇉ f$ on $X$ $($$f_{n}$ *uniformly converges to $f$ on* $X$$)$. Show that $D(f) \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}D(f_{n})$, where $D(f)$ is the set of discontinuities of $f$.

Suppose that $x \in D(f)$. Then $\exists \epsilon > 0 \ \forall \delta >0$ such that $d(x_{n},x) < \delta$ and $\rho(f(x_{n}),f(x)) \geq \epsilon$. Now, since  $f_{n} ⇉ f$ on $X$ we have that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\rho(f_{n}(x),f(x)) < \epsilon, \forall x \in X, \forall n \geq N$. Therefore by the triangle inequality: $$ \rho(f(x),f(x_{n})) \leq \rho(f(x),f_{n}(x)) + \rho(f_{n}(x),f_{n}(x_{n})+\rho(f_{n}(x_{n}), f(x_{n}) < \epsilon+ \rho(f_{n}(x),f_{n}(x_{n}))+\epsilon$$ and so we have that $\rho(f_{n}(x),f_{n}(x_{n})) \geq \epsilon$. Therefore we have a sequence $x_n \to x$ such that $f_{n}(x_{n})$ does not converge to $f_{n}(x)$. So, $x$ is a point of discontinuity of $f_n$. So by definition $x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}D(f_{n})$.

Is this a correct approach to this problem? Any criticism is welcome.

Comment: Uniform convergence (over  metric  spaces) preserves continuity, isn’t it?

Comment: I actually am unsure, I believe I have yet to prove that! If so, that seems it would make this argument pretty straightforward. @TitoEliatron

Comment: Yes, it holds. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_continuity One only needs $Y$ to be a metric space

Comment: @TitoEliatro - gotcha, then I’m assuming all we need to prove is that if $x$ is a discontinuity of $f_n$ (and $f_n$ uniformly converges to $f$), then $x$ is a discontinuity of $f_n$?

Comment: You want to prove that if $f$ is not continuous at $x$ then $f_n$ is not continuous at $x$ for some $n$. The logically equivalent contrapositive says if $f_n$ is continuous at $x$ for all $n$ then $f$ is continous at $x$ and you should be able to use uniform convergence to do that.

Comment: @JohnDouma - Isn’t that what I have shown above in my answer (or at least attempted to)?

Comment: If that's the case, you should explicitly state that you are proving that if $f_n$ is continuous at $x$ for all $n$ then $f$ is continuous. Your proof seems to be a direct attempt rather than to use the contrapositive. Your approach still works. By the way, you have a type on the first line of your proof.

Comment: @JohnDouma - Good to hear! Also, What might be the typo?

Comment: $d(x_n,x)\lt\epsilon$ should be less than $\delta$.

Comment: @JohnDouma - oops, good catch. Thank you for all the feedback!